# Hamiltonian with identity operator: how to visualize the (time-evolution) rotation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, bloch-sphere

For the Hadarmard Hamiltonian, $\hat H = (\hat X+\hat Z)/\sqrt 2$, where $\hat X$ and $\hat Z$ are Pauli matrices. The time evolution of a state under this Hamiltonian could be visualized by a rotation on the Bloch sphere with an axis

$$
\hat n = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, I'm wondering if I have another Hamiltonian defined as

$$
\hat H_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}(\hat X +\hat Z +\hat I)
$$

where $\hat I$ is the identity operator. Then what the role $\hat I$ would have on this Hamiltonian? If I still want to visualize the time-evolution rotation on the Bloch sphere, what the 'new' axis would be?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not change the direction of a ket on the Bloch sphere. Only the total phase of the ket changes. It corresponds to the constant energy shift, as naturally understood from the meaning of 'Hamiltonian'.